# how to integrate amazon affiliate services to my angular app?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework

I am developing an angular app where I need to integrate AMAZON-AFFILIATE services into my app by adding link generated by amazon.

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit more about what exactly your question is? Thanks.

Comment: when you apply for amazon-affiliate It gives a link which redirect to amazon site .How can i use this link in my angular app